# Join query codeigniter with where condition returns all rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my join query for getting data from two tables.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('george_hotel_bkd_customers');
$this->db->where('george_hotel_bookings.bookingref',$ref);
$this->db->join('george_hotel_bookings', 'george_hotel_bookings.user_id = george_hotel_bkd_customers.user_id');    
$query = $this->db->get();
```

According to my `where` condition it returns only one  row but it will returns all the rows with matches the join condition.

Seems like my where condition is not executed here.

please help me

Comment: Your question makes no sense, but join before your where clause.

Comment: swap join and where.

Comment: put join first and then where

Comment: @Kisaragi tried it but didn't worked

Comment: try switching between a right or left join by adding ``right`` or ``left`` as the third param whe you call join.  Ex. ``$this->db->join('george_hotel_bookings', 'george_hotel_bookings.user_id = george_hotel_bkd_customers.user_id','right');``.

Answer (score 0):

What does $ref =, how many results should it pick up roughly?
what do you get when you omit the where? if you get full result then must be an issue with $ref value, or, that is the result.

Just a note, you don't need to select(*), this is default, if this is an just for examples sake, sorry for picking up. You can also add the ->from(whaterver_table) to ->get(whatever_table) You need to add ->get() anyway, so why not remove the ->from() line, just a choice of readability, but i did not realise you could do this for a while, so thought id add it to my answer.

Or another problem solving path is whether the join should be 'left' as 3rd arg. IE is there always a join?

Altering the position or the join in the statement would not make any difference, as Anant suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('george_hotel_bkd_customers');
$this->db->join('george_hotel_bookings', 'george_hotel_bookings.user_id = george_hotel_bkd_customers.user_id');
$this->db->where('george_hotel_bookings.bookingref',$ref);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

always where is last